# How to change the axis interval in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis

Now I have a plot whose interval on y-axis is 1.
But I have two datasets to express. One is very small on y-axis, nearly 0 for example.
Another is relatively large, around 100 for example. If they are plotted in the same graph, 
maybe the small one cannot be found.

So I want to plot this two data point in the same graph. I think I should modify the 
interval on y-axis to by function log(). Then the value on y-axis is expressed as exponent, which is better. So how to realize it?

Comment: `ax.set_yscale('log')`  http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_yscale

Comment: I removed the matlab tag.

Comment: But I plotted a bar graph, using log will makes the bar look like a line segment. Its terrible

Comment: See the duplicate question.  You should edit your question to include the fact that you are plotting bar graphs.